# Using Serial Queues to animate sequence of buttons in Swift on Apple Watch

Tags: swift, asynchronous, watchkit, apple-watch, dispatch

I am playing about with Swift, specifically to create applications on Apple Watch.  I am trying to animate a sequence of buttons in the user interface of the watch.

I have written a function which I pass a WKInterfaceButton into and I expected it to make the button flash by changing the Alpha to 0 and back to 1.
I created a serial queue and understood that any blocks passed into this would be executed in order therefore the instruction to dim the button would be placed in the queue, then the instruction to bring it back, then the same for the next button if i keep calling the function.

Clearly I am missing something basic as nothing happens on screen, any help would be gratefully received!

```
 let alphaTimer = 1.00
var serialQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.apollodev", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL)
private func animateButton(button: WKInterfaceButton) {
        dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
             self.animateWithDuration(self.alphaTimer, animations: { () -> Void in
                button.setAlpha(0)
            })
        }

        dispatch_async(serialQueue) {
               self.animateWithDuration(self.alphaTimer, animations: { () -> Void in
                    button.setAlpha(1)
                })
}
```

Comment: OK, so realise the code above won't work and has to be run on main thread. 
Essentially what I want is 3 buttons on screen (red, yellow, blue) and be able to run through a sequence (red, blue, yellow, red, yellow)... and have the buttons appear to flash which I try to achieve by using the SetAlpha.
Is there any way to just add commands into the main queue:

self.animateWithDuration(self.alphaTimer, animations: { () -> Void in
                button.setAlpha(0) 
and 
self.animateWithDuration(self.alphaTimer, animations: { () -> Void in
                button.setAlpha(0)

Comment: so that they are executed in sequence and animation for blue button doesn't start until the red button has completed etc.

Any help appreciated